# Getting StackOverflowException on RenderSection & ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

It seems that the ViewBag.Title & @RenderSection(..) executes multiple times but i can't figure why it happens

this is a new project, i have just implemented a single controller with a single view
the Index.cshtml contains

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

and the layout:

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Note that it's probably best to copy-paste the code and exception (indicating where the exception occurred) in future so people searching using the error message (for example) can easily find this question. :)

Comment: @George Duckett Ok i'll keep it in mind, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buried beneath your screenshot I can perceive the root of your problem:

```
<a href="@Html.Action("Inde........
    <img src="~/Content/ima....
</a>
```

You wanted to use `Url.Action` and not `Html.Action` [which is something entirely different](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Inde........
    <img src="~/Content/ima....
</a>
```